# git bundle part of the repository

Tags: git

I want to mirror a part of a large repository using got bundle.
My plan was to create a new branch, and delete from it the non relevant files. But the  bundle of this branch contains the history before branching, including all deleted files.

Is there a method to create a bundle without these "leftovers "?

P.s. splitting the module into submodules isn't practical, as deleted files are spread accross directories.
Also, these files should remain in the master branch of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

The only way (I know of) to rewrite history is to do an interactive rebase and delete all the lines you don't want. The process basically replays the development history with the modifications you choose. It's a bit hairy if you go back a long way, and choices you make early in the process might force you to fix up a lot of conflicts later.

The end result is a new branch (you did keep a backup of the original branch, right?) that appears to have exactly the same content, but arrives there by an entirely different route. This means each commit will have a different SHA and the two branches will *not* be compatible for merge purposes.

Basically, I would *not* do this unless the problem changes were very recent and all users of the repository agreed to migrate development to the new branch.

If I just wanted to be able to view the recent history and post back patch files, without moving around too much data, then I'd use a *shallow* clone.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `--orphan` branch and then 'rebase' the required history onto it (faking up the branch you want rebased first so you have a start/end point, noting that rebase doesn't include merges by default)

Then you should be able to bundle the new orphan branch.

Alternatively try `git-archive` - Create an archive of files from a named tree.